# current user firebase functions onRequest

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to get the current user of my app and place it inside a Firebase `onRequest` function?

I am trying the following:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { config } from 'dotenv';

admin.initializeApp();
config();
const axios = require('axios').default;


export const getCurrentUser = functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {

  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  res.send(user);
  console.log(user);

});
```

But I get the following error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being
> deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options). at initializeApp

Here the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to pass a Firebase ID token as a Bearer token in the Authorization header of a request send to an HTTPS Cloud Function, as shown in this [official sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/authorized-https-endpoint), but I would highly recommend using a [Callable Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=1st), for which Firebase Authentication tokens are **automatically** included in requests.

It will be as easy as the following:

```
exports.getCurrentUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  const callerUid = context.auth.uid;
  // ... Then use the Admin SDK methods to get the user, etc.
  // ... See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data   
  // ...
});
```

Or with [functions v2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd):

```
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

exports.getCurrentUser = onCall((request) => {

  const callerUid = request.auth.uid;
  // ... Then use the Admin SDK methods to get the user, etc.
  // ... See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data   
  // ...
});
```

Comment: What happens is that I need to call the function via HTTP request, that is to say: `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/getCurrentUser`, I understand that the `onCall` functions are called from your app and `onRequest` via HTTP request, is that correct?

Comment: "I understand that the onCall functions are called from your app and onRequest via HTTP request, is that correct?" Yes. As explained in the doc, Callable functions are similar but not identical to HTTP functions. To use HTTPS callable functions you must use the client SDK for your platform together with the functions.https backend API (or implement the protocol, which can be complex). So if you **must** call it via an HTTP request you'll need to implement the code from the sample referred to in my answer.

Comment: So do you have any idea what it would look like in an `onRequest` function?

Comment: Yes, you just have to follow the official sample I referred to in my answer: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js